# Растянуть textarea на весь экран?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

Добрый день.

Нужно растянуться `textarea` на весь экран, но просто 100% не сойдет, так как есть padding и ширина или высота получаются больше чем нужно. Использовал calc, но в Safari он не работает.

Пробовал через JQ:

```
object_code_field.css({
    'width': (object_code_field.width()-20)+'px',   // width в CSS указан как 100%
    'height': (object_code_field.height()-20)+'px'  // height в CSS указан как 100%
});
```

Но при масштабировании textarea не растягивается на весь экран.

Прошу помочь с решением данной проблемы.
Так же приветствуется аналоги textarea.

Comment: А [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/JDAZk/) — это если нужно поддерживать buggy box-sizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[box-sizing](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing) — http://jsfiddle.net/Mw4nh/

Answer (score 1):

1. Как выше сказано, можно использовать `box-sizign: border-box;`
2. Если хотите кроссбраузерно, то было дело, написал я функцию одну ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y274v/)):

---

```
function ei() {
    $('.embed').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.width(1);
        if($this.is('textarea')) {
            $this.css({'min-width': '', 'max-width': ''});
        }

        var additionalWidth =
                parseInt($this.css('border-left-width')) +
                parseInt($this.css('border-right-width')) +
                parseInt($this.css('margin-left')) +
                parseInt($this.css('margin-right')) +
                parseInt($this.css('padding-left')) +
                parseInt($this.css('padding-right')),
            parentWidth = $this.parent().width(),
            countedWidth = parentWidth-additionalWidth;

            $this.width(countedWidth);
            if($this.is('textarea')) {
                $this.css({
                    'min-width': countedWidth,
                    'max-width': countedWidth
                });
            }
    });
}
$(document).ready(ei);
$(window).resize(ei);
```